# Remove .svn files from zip file

Tags: linux, unix, svn, command-line, zip

I would like to remove all svn directories from a zip file. Can not find correct pattern. This is the pattern I tried  ".svn/*"
Was able to remove all .class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found pattern. Should work for any directory.
"*/.svn/*"

Answer (score -1):

Avoid the problem in the first place. Don't create your zip file directly from your working copy. Just use [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) to create a new directory *without* the .svn directories, and without any unversioned files, and zip *that* instead.